# How to access data from AngularJS Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm having trouble accessing my user information from the angular scope for an HTTP request. I can see the information I need in the developer tools, but I am having trouble accessing it.

Here's what I have:

```
    var scope = angular.element("#comment").scope();
    console.log(scope);
    //console.log(scope.navvm.currentUser.name);
```

I've tried the commented out portion, but it doesn't work. When I run the not commented out portion; I can see this in my developer tools

[image]

I crossed out username and email.

Here's **navigation controller**:

```
(function () {

angular
    .module('meanApp')
    .controller('navigationCtrl', navigationCtrl);

navigationCtrl.$inject = ['$location','authentication'];
function navigationCtrl($location, authentication) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.isLoggedIn = authentication.isLoggedIn();

    vm.currentUser = authentication.currentUser();

}

})();
```

Here's **navigation directive**:

(function () {

```
angular
    .module('meanApp')
    .directive('navigation', navigation);

function navigation () {
    return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: '/common/directives/navigation/navigation.template.html',
    controller: 'navigationCtrl as navvm',
    scope: '@?'
    };
}

})();
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Typically if you need to access scope variables in a service, for example, you would pass them to the service method as parameters. You shouldn't really ever need to access scope in the manner you've tried here.

Comment: Agreed. It should be in a service. This is a proof of concept at the moment. Long term it will be in a service.

Comment: Can you show more of the surrounding code? Or perhaps even a [MCVE].

Comment: plus, you shouldn't use scope. main reason being Angular2 has dropped the $scope in favour of class variables

Comment: It's at the beginning of the script tag to be used later in the script. The comments ID is an angular directive.

Comment: @Lex I added controller and directive

Comment: So where are you calling the code at the top of your question?

Comment: Inside of a script tag on an html page @Lex

Comment: Hmm, why? That is very un-Angular. All of your scope references should be occurring in a controller, not a script tag on a view.

Comment: @Lex  This is for stripe payment; I need to send the username in the request to update a data value server side. Should I create a service for this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with stripe payment, but yes - I would recommend trying to write it so you're doing everything through Angular. In this case a service seems to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a logging statement *within* the controller in question.

So, for your case, just add a `console.log(currrentUser)` in the controller's definition.

**EDIT**: You are not using $scope. You're using the `controller as` syntax. If you need to debug data that way, then add a $scope variable that refers to the current controller: `$scope.navvm = this;`

Cheers!

Comment: I don't understand the reason for doing so. I know the controller is working properly. I can see the data in the developer tools

Comment: if you can give a plunkr then we could be of more help

Comment: Never done a plunker before. Plus there's a JWT that's stored in the broswer that the controller is using. Not sure if plunkr could replicate that.

Comment: I added controller and directive